# iOS: implement SharePoint Designer (Workflows only) functionality

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, apple-ios

Is it possible to implement operations on Workflows (like in SharePoint Designer) on iOS?
Maybe I could call SharePoint's services to get a list of workflows, nodes in each workflow and draw it as a tree in iOS?

This is a general question, and I would like to get a high-level picture of how can I do that.

Comment: sp2007, SP2010 or SP2013? Which edition?

Comment: I don't think he knows. I think it's a general question to determine if he / his company can make an iOS app to manage certain functionality of SharePoint from the iPhone or iPad...

Comment: @SteveB we expect to use SP2010 or SP2013. This is a topic of discussion for now. Is it makes significant difference according to my question?

Comment: 2010 introduced Visio Services with visual workflow viewing. Quite obscure product, but it may help you (if you can use the Enterprise licence)

Comment: Thanks @SteveB. While researching I've found that Visio Services is kind of Lite version of SP Designer. Is it possible to open SP Designer in a browser on iOS? If so, it isn't necessary to write Designer-like iOS-client and deal with services to work with workflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>There is no web service to interact with workflows. (You could write a custom one I guess).</strike>

## Edit

There is a [Workflow Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981383%28v=office.12%29.aspx#2): workflow.asmx, it is just undocumented for SP 2010.

What kind of operations are you trying to perform? That is a pretty broad area, and depending on the desired action, there may be different "better" approaches to take.

If you're trying to initiate a workflow, one way you could achieve that would be to set the workflow to start on the creation of a new list item (and hit that with Lists.asmx). This method also allows you to pass in initialization data in the list's columns.

If you're trying to act on a specific step in a workflow, I don't believe you'd be able to do so without writing a custom web service, or a custom workflow to act on your target.

Check out this similar question on SO: [SharePoint, Workflow and Web Services - restart workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357794/sharepoint-workflow-and-web-services-restart-workflow)

Comment: That isn't entirely true, there is a workflow web service with some operations available to it. GetTemplatesForItem fetches all workflows for a particular item and StartWorkflow will trigger a workflow. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981383(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thank you rjcup3 @PirateEric! I need to implement basic operations: create, initialize, edit and finish workflows. Is it possible via Services (custom maybe)? Or is it better to do that via browser (link to Designer Online, if it is exists)?

Comment: @PirateEric The workflow web service was only in 2007 though right? It isn't on the list of 2010 web services.

Comment: It's there in 2010, I just checked our farm.  AlterToDo 
ClaimReleaseTask 
GetTemplatesForItem 
GetToDosForItem 
GetWorkflowDataForItem 
GetWorkflowTaskData 
StartWorkflow

Comment: Thank you @PirateEric, rjcup3. Is it possible to access SharePoint Designer from a browser?

Comment: Looks like it isn't possible to access Designer from a browser. @PirateEric could you please point me which services I should use to Edit and Finish workflow?

Comment: There aren't any for those operations. You'd have to program your own to do that. The operations listed above are the only native ones.

Comment: @PirateEric, if I will write a custom service, will I be able to deploy it in Office 365 (microsoft's cloud)?

Comment: I haven't used o365 so I'm not 100% certain on the limitations, I want to say no, but they have so many levels of service on that, I can't give you an accurate answer.

Comment: I don't think you can. Office 365 is extremely locked down.

Comment: @PirateEric, is it true that if I complete all workflow tasks (with AlterToDo) the workflow will finish? (Automatically, without my intervention).

Comment: The documentation implies that, I've never used that operation so I can't say.